# How to compute log(exp(x)-exp(y)) numerically stable

Tags: numerical-computing

I'm trying to compute log(exp(x)-exp(y)); since this is not sum anymore, I can't use LogSumExp and things can still get very ugly if exp(x) or exp(y) is large (e.g.) exp(32) or something).

How do I do this more safely?

Comment: Assuming x>y, you can do `log(exp(x)-exp(y))=log(exp(x) * [exp(x)-exp(y)]/exp(x)) = x + log(1-exp(y-x))`, which may be a bit more stable